# How do I refresh files available to CommandT in vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm having this occasional problem:

In macvim I create a new file in the current directory using

```
:e foo.coffee
```

I save that file and continue working in macvim. I close and restart macvim, and use `<Leader>T` to try to open that file but it's not being listed.

I see `foo.bar` in the directory and can open it manually, but why is not available for CommandT? Is there a way to sort of *punch* CommandT in the head and refresh the files available to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typing this in mvim worked out for me in the end:

`:ClearCtrlPCache`

Answer (score 31):

You can also use `<C-f>` (that's control-f), when CommandT is open.

Ref: https://github.com/wincent/Command-T under the section titled:

> The following mappings are active when either the prompt or the file listing has focus

(I would like to link to the heading, but the README is plain text, so there are no heading anchors).

Comment: This is by far the easiest.

Comment: Agree with @JezenThomas - to me this answer should be the accepted one. I wonder if (for any reason) it didn't work for the OP...

Answer (score 16):

Yes, I also have a mapping for it, but you can type the command manually if you so like:

```
noremap <F5> :CommandTFlush<CR>
```

Comment: what does `noremap` do? entering `:CommandTFlush` doesn't seem to do it for me ....

Comment: `noremap` just adds a mapping for the normal mode. If you enter `:CommandTFlush` from the command line and it doesn't work, there's probably another issue. I believe you are starting vim from your home directory, so CommandT will only search for a certain number of files and then stop, but I cannot be sure.

Comment: yeah, i'm getting `Not an editor command: CommandTFlush`. I installed [yadr](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles); they must be using something else. thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: looks like yadr is using CtrlP, and has CtrlP's flush `:ClearCtrlPCache` command bound to Cmd-Shift-P  (https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/plugin/settings/ctrlp.vim)

Comment: in the end it turned out that this was because i was starting macvim using `mvim .`. doing it that way doesn't connect to the pasteboard or refresh files in the directory (probably other things too). i had to do `open -a MacVim` and everything worked fine. thanks for your help!